# Alamofire sending an extraneous & sign before my params

Tags: swift, alamofire

```
private let manager: Alamofire.Manager = { ...

 manager.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL).responseJSON {
            response in
            fulfill(response)
        }
```

it can make a URL like `myurl.com/?&fruit=apple&color=red` . I expect the first & not to be there.

Comment: Please paste your entire url here

Comment: @DharmbirSingh, the url is confidential for a client.

Comment: I don't see anything in RFC 3986 that would prohibit this.  Is that not a valid URL query string?

Comment: @Ssswift yeah, it is valid. Just the way the server was designed theydidn't like this. I convinced them to support it (as they should)